# Sharepoint: Add css and javascript to a web part page

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a web part Page and need to add css and javascript code to it. I am using Sharepoint 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could in theory link a javascript file from the master page, but more commonly you link scripts with specific web parts, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584169%28office.11%29.aspx)